# How to get a list of files with shared-link using GoogleAPIClientForREST [Swift]

Tags: swift, google-drive-api

I am building an app where users can download files with Google Drive's shared-link.

Trying to get a list of files with shared folder link, but couldn't find any document explaining how to do that.

### What I have tried so far

1. to use GoogleAPIClientForREST 'fetchObject'

```
googleDriveService.fetchObject(with: url, objectClass: nil, executionParameters: nil) { ticket, any, e in
                print("thicket", ticket, any, e)
            }
```

(where I tested with 'link' as https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EVHGkbGwlFAi16DhVG4ZoYEng6UQ7_Km?usp=sharing)
But it returns error below

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Got unexpected content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8''
```

2. to use GoogleAPIClientForREST 'query'

```
let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
        query.q = "'\(url)'"
        query.spaces = "drive"
        query.corpora = "user"
        
        googleDriveService.executeQuery(query) { (_, result, error) in
}
```

Which returns 'Invalid query' error.

3. to use GoogleAPIClientForREST 'query' with fileID

```
guard let url = URL(string: text) else {
    return
}
googleDriveService.executeQuery(GTLRDriveQuery_FilesGet.query(withFileId: url.lastPathComponent)) { ticket, any, e in }
```

Which again, returns below error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Got unexpected content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8''
```

Is it possible to do this with GoogleAPIClientForREST?

If not, what would be the alternate?

If I need to provide more details, I am happy to do so.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself.

I could simply send query below using GoogleAPIClientForREST.
It returns a list of files!

```
let comps = sharedURL.components(separatedBy: "/")
guard let folderID = comps.last?.components(separatedBy: "?").first else {
   failed()
   return
}
let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
                query.q = "'\(folderID)' in parents"
                query.spaces = "drive"
                query.corpora = "allDrives"
                query.includeItemsFromAllDrives = true
                query.supportsAllDrives = true
```